# The SharePoint website cannot be displayed

Tags: iis, dns

Dunno what happened, just walked away from my server, came back and suddnely SharePoint website cannot be displayed. However, I can Access CA and it shows that the content is still there. I restarded IIS services, but it didn't help. Any solutions? I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013 and I runned SharePoint Server installation, clicked repair and after 3s I canceled it. Maybe this has to do something with it?

```
Some logs:
The DNS server has detected that it is no longer the Key Master for zone apt-test.local. The Key Master role has been seized or transferred to apt-test-sp.apt-test.local.

The DNS server is waiting for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed. The DNS server service cannot start until the initial synchronization is complete because critical DNS data might not yet be replicated onto this domain controller. If events in the AD DS event log indicate that there is a problem with DNS name resolution, consider adding the IP address of another DNS server for this domain to the DNS server list in the Internet Protocol properties of this computer. This event will be logged every two minutes until AD DS has signaled that the initial synchronization has successfully completed.
```

But these are log after restart, they are always the same then I turn on the machine.

Comment: Make sure all SharePoint services are up and running (the IIS app pools, the timer service, and so on). A physical reboot of the server should be an easy way to eliminate that it is a service that is stopped

Comment: I did physical reboot and attached logs after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Does the IIS log show anything about the request?

If not, try Network Monitor to analyze incoming data.

[MS Network Monitor download site from microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)

You should do the whole repair by the way if you started it once.